# Left join issue with reference table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, left-join

Im having a bit of difficulty with getting user information from one place to another.

There are 3 tables **dbo.gr_usersource** and **dbo.gr_task** and **dbo.gr_user**

In the `dbo.gr_task` table a column is filled with values that match entries in `dbo.gr_usersource` table that has another value that corresponds to the value in the `dbo.gr_user` table. You could call it a reference table between `dbo.gr_task` and `dbo.gr_user` tables.

My query looks like this;

```
select
      dbo.gr_task.task_number
    , dbo.gr_task.task_name
    , dbo.gr_task.task_description

from dbo.gr_task

left join dbo.gr_user AS Handler
    on dbo.gr_usersource.usersource_user = Handler.user_id
    and dbo.gr_task.task_handler = dbo.gr.usersource.usersource.id
```

The last step would be to get the column user_name from table user when the join is working.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed mediator table in your join so use as per below-

```
SELECT dbo.gr_task.task_number,dbo.gr_task.task_name, dbo.gr_task.task_description 
FROM dbo.gr_task AS gt
LEFT JOIN dbo.gr_usersource gus ON gt.task_handler=gus.usersource.id
LEFT JOIN dbo.gr_user AS gu ON gus.usersource_user=gu.user_id;
```

Note: If you want only matching rows in all 3 tables then you should use normal join instead of left join.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.
Note that there are no columns from your joined tables in your select list so left joins would have no impact on your result set.

Inner joins will filter your results set even if you bring back no columns, i.e., enforce the join condition to match rows in both tables.

```
SELECT
      t.task_number
    , t.task_name
    , t.task_description

FROM dbo.gr_task t

INNER JOIN dbo.gr_usersource us
    ON us.usersource.id = t.task_handler

INNER JOIN dbo.gr_user u
    ON u.user_id = us.usersource_user
```